# How to gather useful data for autocompletion?

Tags: search, autocomplete, autosuggest

im trying to implement a typical autocompletion-box, like you know from amazon.com.
There you go, type in a letter and you get a reasonable suggest about what you might try to enter into the search-box.

The box itself will be implemented by jquery, the persistence-layer and suggest algorithm will be based on Apache Lucene/Solr and its Suggest-Feature.
Additionaly i get a weighted suggestion into the result, using WFST-Suggestion by lucene.

My problem is, **what does e.g. amazon to achieve this kind of reasonable data**?
I mean where do they get all this keywords and score, so it makes sense?

Is it a pure hand-made style information on each product? What I think would be real tough.
Or is it possible to gather the data using things like clustering or classification from machine-learning-theory? (then I could use mahout or carrot2).

Looking on amazon suggestions, I think the data contains:

- name of the product
- producer/manufacturer/author of the product/book
- product-features (like color, type, size)

Does it contain more?

The next thing would be that it looks that the suggestion itself is ranked. **How do they receive this kind of *score* to weight the suggestions?**
Is it a simple user-click-path-tracking, where you look, what the user typed into the box and what he selected or which product he looks afterward?

Is this kind of score computed on each query (maybe cached) using some logic? (**Which?** maybe bayes theorem?)

Answer (score 0):

They might use something as simple as building an n-gram model from user queries and/or product names and use that to predict the most likely auto-completions.